# Select default array from for each in option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, foreach, key

I want to set default selected from 'Rome'

here is my js

```
var listCity = {
 "Popular": [
              { "cityname": "London", "code": "LDN" },
              { "cityname": "Rome", "code": "ROM" },
              { "cityname": "Madrid", "code": "MDR" }
            ],
 "Germany":[
              { "cityname": "Hamburg", "code": "HMB" },
              { "cityname": "Frankfurt", "code": "FRN" }
           ]
}

Object.keys(listCity).forEach(function(key) {
  var $group = $('<optgroup label="' + key + '"></optgroup>');

listCity[key].forEach(function(obj) {
 $group.append('<option value="' + obj.code[1] + '">' + obj.cityname + '</option>')
 })
 })
```

I try this, but still bug. Anybody help or suggestion? 
Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/0c1js6wa/1/

Thank you

Comment: You can use `$('#fromCity option')[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');` If you have control of the dataset I would add a selected property and go off of that though and set the selected attribute when you build the select.

Comment: @Loktar Ohh, thank you Loktar, I still studied JavaScript. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the value just after appending the optgroup html in the select element.

```
 $('#fromCity').append($group);

  $('#fromCity').val("ROM");
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5gpbvhff/

Comment: oh my god, it's just add value. Thanks @Deep

Answer (score 1):

Just do like in your fiddle, only add this to the end:

```
$('#fromCity').val('ROM');
```

Tested :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Hope it helps :)

**Just use this:**

```
 $('select option[value="ROM"]').prop("selected",true);
```

**Here's program working:**

```js
var listCity = {
  "Popular": [
    { "cityname": "London", "code": "LDN" },
    { "cityname": "Rome", "code": "ROM" },
    { "cityname": "Madrid", "code": "MDR" }
  ],
  "Germany": [
    { "cityname": "Hamburg", "code": "HMB" },
    { "cityname": "Frankfurt", "code": "FRN" }
  ]
}

Object.keys(listCity).forEach(function(key) {
  var $group = $('<optgroup label="' + key + '"></optgroup>');

  $('select option[value="ROM"]').prop("selected",true);

  listCity[key].forEach(function(obj) {
    $group.append('<option value="' + obj.code + '">' + obj.cityname + '</option>')
  })

  $('#fromCity').append($group);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="fromCity"></select>
```

Comment: yes, thank you @HenryDev it's work, I have many option to choose it

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of your data I would add a selected property to it like this,

```
  {
   "cityname": "Rome",
    "code": "ROM",
    "selected": true
  },
```

And I would select it the following way.

```
  listCity[key].forEach(function(obj) {
    const selected = obj.selected ? 'selected' : '';
    $group.append(`<option ${selected} value="${obj.code}">${obj.cityname}</option>`);
  });
```

Also note I'm using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in this example because they are easier to read but not supported in IE.

[live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0c1js6wa/5/)

Otherwise you could do something like this

`$('#fromCity option')[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');`

[live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0c1js6wa/6/)

Or set the val like others have said above, (@HenryDev is probably the best one if you take this route).  I prefer to use the [selected attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) to define whats initially selected.